# Show that the number of solutions to $x^n\equiv 1 \pmod p$ is $\gcd(n, p-1)$, where $p$ is a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primitive-roots

> Show that the number of solutions to $x^n\equiv 1 \pmod p$ is $\gcd(n, p-1)$.

I know the argument should specifically use primitive roots (the desired one based off the stuff I've learned), but not sure how to extend it to a proof. Would appreciate help.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2728762/let-p-be-a-prime-number-show-that-the-number-of-solutions-to-xk-equiv-1-p#comment5632193_2728762

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, then thr number of solutions to $x^n \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ is the same as that of $g^{nk} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, or $nk \equiv 0 \pmod{p - 1}$, which is $\gcd(n, p - 1)$.

Comment: Just trying to be extra careful here but what fact do you use to conclude the last step?

Comment: Sorry should have clarified but meant more the step where you conclude we can figure out the number of solutions to this $g^{nk} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ by $nk \equiv 0 \pmod{p - 1}$

Comment: @SS' This step uses the fact that $\mathrm{ord}_p(g)=p-1$.

Comment: Oh yeah of course! Makes sense, thanks!