# Suppose for a prime $p$, where d | p - 1. Prove that $d$ solutions to ($x^d$ - 1) (mod p) = 0,

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that for a prime $p$, where d | p - 1, ($x^d$ - 1) (mod p) = 0

I've tested this and see that it works for (p,d): (5,2), (7,3), (11,2)

Example in case this is confusing: (5,2) is ($x^2$ - 1) (mod 5) = 0, which has the 2 solutions of x = 1,4

(7,3) is $x^3$ - 1 (mod 7) = 0, which has the 3 solutions of x = 1,2,4

We can factor $x^n$ - 1 into (x-1)($x^n-1$)($x^n-2$)... + $x^2$ + 1

So x = 1 will always be a solution.

Is factoring like this the way to go? Or am I missing something obvious?

All help welcomed!

Comment: This follows quickly from the existence of primitive roots, for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $p$ be a prime number. Show that the number of solutions to $x^k \equiv 1 \pmod p$ is $gcd(k, p-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2728762/let-p-be-a-prime-number-show-that-the-number-of-solutions-to-xk-equiv-1-p). Of course, in your specific case, $\gcd(d,p-1) = d$.